# Aframe and aframe-ar: display video stream in div instead of fullscreen

Tags: aframe

I am using *aframe-ar* and need the video stream to be displayed in the same *div* as the scene is embedded to.

I am trying with the default scene:

```
<a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;'>
 <a-marker preset="hiro">
  <a-box position='0 0.5 0' material='color: black;'></a-box>
 </a-marker>
</a-scene>
```

The rendered box is successfully embedded in the surrounding `div`, but the video stream of my webcam is fullscreen and placed behind other html-elements.

I also tried to specify the camera explicitly but that did not help!

In short: I want to get the video also embedded in the surrounding `div`.

- A-Frame Version: 0.8.0
- Platform / Device:  Chrome / Desktop PC

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ar.js` spreads the camera feed on the entire `body` element. If you don't want to mess with the source code, You can contain it within an `iframe`:

```
<iframe src="myScene.html"></iframe>
```

Working glitch [here](https://glitch.com/~embedded-ar).

Comment: Works in the iframe, thanks. A little challange now is to integrate it into an angular 6 application....