# AFrame - Set Size of Camera Feed

Tags: aframe, ar.js

My last question was marked as duplicate: [A-Frame AR - Set Size of Scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66346413/a-frame-ar-set-size-of-scene)

Here is the question that it was marked duplicate of: [Aframe and aframe-ar: display video stream in div instead of fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951913/aframe-and-aframe-ar-display-video-stream-in-div-instead-of-fullscreen)

Using iframe is not the optimal solution for me, I need the AR to be present on my webpage. The answerer alludes to changing the source code to be able to resize the scene and camera video. Can someone help me achieve this?

Comment: Hi, I was hoping you'd leave a comment under the other answer, still I'll do my best to help. I'd start with looking how ar.js creates the `video` element, though I'm sure it will be way more complicated and error prone than using an i-frame.

Comment: Hi, I tried to leave a comment but I was not allowed due to my reputation not being high enough /:

Comment: The reason I need the scene to be rendered in my webpage is because I have buttons on my page that I want to be able to click and change the src attribute of my a-entity for the 3D model. However, I can’t do that (at least not easily it seems) if the AR is inside the iframe. Really appreciate your continued help on this!

Comment: Sure thing, I'll let you know once I get a hold on this thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tldr](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/arjs/resized/index.html).

Afaik [arjs](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/) has hardcoded sizes and multiple boundaries all over the place to keep the library universal (different devices with different aspect ratios, mobile portrait vs landscape etc...).

Re-creating it all with "embedding" options would be a huge project so I'll focus on a simple example with a non - resizable window.

*Disclaimer: most of the following is just my take, mostly showing which parts I changed and why. All of this could be done in many other ways.*

**0. a wrapper element**

So the idea is to be able to embed the video + scene into some div, like here
[image]

You can see both the video and scene are contained within a div - `#arjs-cell`.
So just after the namespace I've added my variable for keeping my wrapper element, and a setter, which will also reparent the video:

```
var THREEx = THREEx || {}
THREEx.wrapperElement = null;
THREEx.setWrapperElement = function(wrapperEl, video) {
  THREEx.wrapperElement = wrapperEl
  wrapperEl.appendChild(video);
}
```

**1.  The video element**

Upon creation the video element is given multiple style attributes ([source](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/blob/master/three.js/build/ar.js#L2922-L2928)) like `position`, `top`, `left`, `zIndex`). In this case I've just threw out the `left` position and changed the `z-index`.

The width / height is a completely different story. For the first `10000 * 1000`ms `arjs` recalculates multiple things including the video size ([source](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/blob/master/aframe/src/system-arjs.js#L211-L225)). It makes it difficult to change the elements "from the outside". Anyway one of those recalculated things is the `video` element size, which is based on the `window` dimensions ([source](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/blob/master/three.js/build/ar.js#L3158))

We can get cut in with our wrapper:

```
ARjs.Source.prototype.onResizeElement = function () {
// (...)
  var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
  if (THREEx.wrapperElement) {
      const bounds = THREEx.wrapperElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      screenWidth = THREEx.wrapperElement.offsetWidth;
      screenHeight = THREEx.wrapperElement.offsetHeight;
      // by default the video parent is the window, so top is 0;
      this.domElement.style.top = bounds.top + 'px';
  }
```

**2. The a-frame scene**

To adjust the scene `arjs` sets the body dimensions to the `<video>` element ( ([source](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/blob/master/aframe/src/system-arjs.js#L179-L182)) forcing an update in `a-frame`. Since we don't want to mess with the `<body>`, lets do the same on the `wrapperElement`:

```
AFRAME.registerSystem('arjs', {
// (...)
  // ugly kludge to get resize on aframe... not even sure it works
  if (arProfile.contextParameters.trackingBackend !== 'tango' && THREEx.wrapperElement) {
    arSource.copyElementSizeTo(THREEx.wrapperElement)
  }
```

*arSource.copyElementSizeTo()* will mess with the margins, so lets comment that out:

```
ARjs.Source.prototype.copyElementSizeTo = function (otherElement) {
if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight) {
   //landscape
   otherElement.style.width = this.domElement.style.width
   otherElement.style.height = this.domElement.style.height
   // otherElement.style.marginLeft = this.domElement.style.marginLeft
   // otherElement.style.marginTop = this.domElement.style.marginTop
}
// (...)
```

**3. Putting it all to use**

Now we can wait for the video (and `arjs` core) to be fully initialized, and do our magic:

```
window.addEventListener("arjs-video-loaded", evt => {
  const video = evt.detail.component;
  const wrapper = document.querySelector("#arjs-cell")
  THREEx.setWrapperElement(wrapper, video)
})
```

You can check it out [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/arjs/resized/resized.html).

---

It really would be way easier not to break the library and use an `iframe`. You can easily call functions withing the `iframed` website - check it out [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/arjs/resized/arjs_iframe.html)

Comment: let me know if its understandable whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the work you've done. While complex for sure, it is understandable. I agree on your take that it would be better to use an iframe, and calling functions to change the iframe content is doable as shown by your demo but also as I have done some research on it on my own.Thanks again!

Comment: @HunterEstrada if you think its extensive and complete feel free to mark the answer

Comment: im adding ar.js into iframe but its not detecting nft image , if i load fullscreen it detect the image , there is no error on console, any idea?

Comment: I can try it out later on android, but I don't have a phone with iOS