# How to change the size of <a-scene> in Browser?

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I don't want to have my a-scene in fullscreen. I tried to add "embedded" to the scene and then change it with css but that does not work.
My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="aframe/aframe.js"></script>
<script src="js/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<script src="js/gestures.js"></script>

<body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  <a-scene embedded arjs renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;" gesture-detector
    id="scene">
    <a-marker type="pattern" preset="custom" url="/pattern/ifgi-pattern.patt" id="a-marker">
      <a-entity position="0 0 0" scale="0.8 0.8 0.8" gltf-model="/gltf/car_model/scene.gltf" class="clickable"
        gesture-handler="minScale: 0.25; maxScale: 10" id="a-entity"></a-entity>
    </a-marker>
    <a-entity camera id="camera">
  </a-scene>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my css:

```
.a-scene { display: block; width: 50%; }
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this? I just want to add a bootstrap navbar but the scene always overlaps the navbar.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: have you try `a-scene{ display: block; width: 50%; }` ? because `.`<- `point = class`

Comment: thanks! but it still is fullscreen..

Comment: `ar.js` is quite difficult to handle because of the video feed. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951913/aframe-and-aframe-ar-display-video-stream-in-div-instead-of-fullscreen) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66358428/aframe-set-size-of-camera-feed) questions

Comment: Okay, <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951913/aframe-and-aframe-ar-display-video-stream-in-div-instead-of-fullscreen> this solved my problem, thanks Piotr!